# Why are backticks removed after saving in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, prettier

```
  const categoryIcons = {
    'All Books': LocalLibraryIcon,
    'Business Management': AnalyticsIcon,
    'Biographies and Memoirs': PeopleIcon,
    Design: DesignServicesIcon,
    'Economics and Politics': AccountBalanceIcon,
    Fiction: AutoFixHighIcon,
    'Health and Fitness': MonitorHeartIcon,
    'Money and Investing': ShowChartIcon,
    'Non-Fiction': LibraryBooksIcon,
    Psychology: PsychologyIcon,
    Poetry: LocalFloristIcon,
    'Science and Nature': ScienceIcon,
    'Self-Improvement': TrendingUpIcon,
    Technology: CodeIcon,
  };
```

I want to put backticks around design, fiction, psychology, poetry, and technology. I'm using Prettier as my default formatter. Whenever I save the backticks are removed from these words.

Comment: Try extension bisect (in command palette) to determine which extension is causing this issue.

Comment: Because they're pointless (even if you mean `'` as for the other property names, which are not backticks). The point of Prettier is to **not** spend time on irrelevant layout issues, but if you insist this is one of the few things that's configurable: https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#quote-props.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry for inadvertently stealing your comment as an answer, I could swear there was no link when I read it. I'm marking my answer as CW to avoid karma farming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because those are [single quotes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/single_quote) (not [backticks](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/backtick)), and they are not *necessary*. Quotes are only needed when the key has characters that need escaping, like spaces.

This setting is configured by [Prettier's `quote-props` option](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#quote-props), which has the default value of `as-needed`. This means that quotes will only be kept if they are required.

If you don't like this behavior, you can select one of the other options:

> - `"as-needed`" - Only add quotes around object properties where required.
> - `"consistent"` - If at least one property in an object requires quotes, quote all properties.
> - `"preserve"` - Respect the input use of quotes in object properties.